# How to define Directory in Azure Storage Container with Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-storage

I know to how to create Storage and Container. But is it possible to create "directory"?

I find followings, but not for creating directory.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "examplestoraccount"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  name                  = "vhds"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of account is it - Data Lake Gen 2 or regular storage account?

Comment: Account kind : StorageV2 (general purpose v2) Hierarchical namespace: Disabled

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that you cannot because regular storage accounts (i.e. which are not Data Lake Gen 2) do not have the concept of actual directories.

The directories you see are `virtual` and are essentially the blob prefix e.g. if you upload a blob with name `images/my-image.png`, `images` will be presented as a directory.

Even when you click on the "Add Directory" button in Azure Portal, you will see the following message:

[image]